# Creating a Next.js app in VS Code does not have 'Pages' or 'Styles' folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, npx

When creating a Next.js app in VS Code, I run the following command: 'npx create-next-app@latest' and go through the process of creating the app. However, Next.js's website shows that I should have a 'pages' and 'styles' folder along with the 'app' and 'public' folder. I am unsure if this has to do with the 'Would you like to use...' section when creating the app if I am selecting the wrong options or what.

['Would you like to use...' section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D0jC.png)
[Top level files and folders I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7AZq.png)

I updated Node.js and recreated the application multiple times using different selections in the 'Would you like to use...' section. I was hoping the folders would appear, but no success. I am unsure where to go here as I am new to using Next.js.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you create a new project with the latest `create-next-app`, it uses the recently released [App Router](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4#nextjs-app-router) feature by default. Hence, your project contains the `app` directory instead of `pages`.

```bash
$ npx create-next-app@latest
✔ What is your project named? … nextjs-project
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? … No
```

```bash
$ tree -d -L 1 nextjs-project
nextjs-project
├── app
├── node_modules
└── public
```

This is the default project structure moving forward, and you can find all relevant documentation and examples under the "Using App Router" section of Next.js docs.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

However, if you prefer not to use the App Router, you should answer "No" to the "Use App Router (recommended)?" question. In this case your project will contain the `pages` directory.

```bash
$ npx create-next-app@latest 
✔ What is your project named? … nextjs-project
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? … No
```

```bash
$ tree -d -L 1 nextjs-project
nextjs-project
├── node_modules
├── pages
├── public
└── styles
```

You can find legacy Pages Router documentation under the "Using Pages Router" section of Next.js docs.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you for the info on that. Appreciate it!

Comment: I ditched learning nextjs because of this, multiple times. I considered this as mis-alignment of application and the documentation. @vercel please mention about the pages stuff in the "create-next-app".

Comment: oh my god this got so complicated compared to before. total bad move on their part.

Answer (score 1):

As per Next.JS documentation  the root layout (`RootLayout`) has replaced the `_app.js` and  `_document.js` files. Look into [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts).

Comment: Please add some more information into the answer itself. Referencing to a source is great, however please also add the relevant parts of the source to your answer.

Comment: If documentation were clear, this question would not exist. Please add context and healthy criticism. :P

Answer (score 0):

Official Example:
https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide#app-directory-setup

**1. app/providers.tsx**

```
'use client'

import { CacheProvider } from '@chakra-ui/next-js'
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export function Providers({ 
    children 
  }: { 
  children: React.ReactNode 
  }) {
  return (
    <CacheProvider>
      <ChakraProvider>
        {children}
      </ChakraProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}
```

**2. app/layout.tsx**

```
import { Providers } from "./providers";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```